# how to use max function in sub select on one table

Tags: sql, max

I have a query in the medicare enrollment database that I use to populate the number of cred cov request. However I need the lastupd_TS field to filter only the max value.  When I do this I get an error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a
>   subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column
>   being aggregated is an outer reference.

Here is the query:

```
Select Distinct CONTACT_ID ,CREATED_TS,LASTUPD_TS,(LASTUPD_TS) as LAST_UPDATE
from tblCCPMedicareSpecific_Archive
where LASTUPD_TS=(Select MAX(lastupd_TS))and (OWNER_DEPT = 'LBECAS POA Enro') AND (CREATED_TS BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-01-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                      '2013-12-31 00:00:00', 102))
```

My question is how can I get this to filter to max value as I can't use a having clause because multiple dates will be in this column and I only want the max or last date entered

Answer (score 0):

Would this not work

```
Select CONTACT_ID, CREATED_TS, MAX(LASTUPD_TS) as LASTUPD_TS, MAX(LASTUPD_TS) as LAST_UPDATE 
from tblCCPMedicareSpecific_Archive 
where (OWNER_DEPT = 'LBECAS POA Enro') AND (CREATED_TS BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-01-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-12-31 00:00:00', 102))
group by CONTACT_ID, CREATED_TS
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you just want a DISTINCT row but only want the MAX of LASTUPD_TS, I think you'd be better off using GROUPing. This will return only one row per your GROUP selection (in this case one row per CONTACT_ID and CREATED_TS). I have a feeling this isn't quite what you need either... is there only one row per unique CONTACT_ID? Does every row for a specific CONTACT_ID have the same value for CREATED_TS? If so, you could change the 
GROUP BY to just CONTACT_ID and use MIN(CREATED_TS) as the SELECT for that column.

edit: Also, I'd suggest that you also consider changing your BETWEEN filter to CREATED_TS BETWEEN >= '2013-01-01'AND CREATED_TS < '2014-01-01 00:00:00'. The current version would exclude anything that happened on 12/31/2013 except at midnight at the first second of that day.

```
SELECT CONTACT_ID
    ,CREATED_TS
    ,MAX(LASTUPD_TS) AS MAX_LASTUPD_TS

FROM tblCCPMedicareSpecific_Archive
WHERE (OWNER_DEPT = 'LBECAS POA Enro')
    AND (
        CREATED_TS BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-01-01 00:00:00', 102)
            AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-12-31 00:00:00', 102)
        )
GROUP BY CONTACT_ID, CREATED_TS
```